# How to limit characters for react-content-edittable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I am trying to use this react component to create a content editable div:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable

But I have been unable to limit the characters for the input.

here is my code for handling change:

```
const onChange = (e: ContentEditableEvent) => {
    const sanitized = sanitizeHtml(e.target.value, sanitizeConf);
    if (sanitized.length < 10) {
      text.current = `${e.target.value}`;
    }
  };
```

component jsx:

```
<ContentEditable
            onInput={onInput}
            className={`${style.innerDiv} ${isValid() ? '' : style.error}`}
            html={`<h1>${text.current}</h1>`}
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
          />
```

Comment: add `e.preventDefault()` inside `onChange`

Comment: I get the following error: preventDefault is not a funciton